# ASP.NET MVC 3: Which dll's need to be deployed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

Which files need to be marked Copy Local to "True" when deploying a ASP.NET MVC 3 application on a server that does not have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed?

Comment: check new easy way to do this with VS2010 SP1 [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg286946.aspx) i.e. answer is none (for the MVC3 references)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

> System.Web.Mvc
>
> Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
>
> System.Web.Razor
>
> System.Web.WebPages
>
> System.Web.WebPages.Razor
>
> System.Web.Helpers
>
> System.Web.WebPages.Deployment

Comment: This is no longer correct with the RTM version, System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll is now required.

Comment: Do not deploy System.Web.WebPages.Administration.Dll as that will cause you more issues.

Comment: This is even easier with SP1, [check out](http://paulstack.co.uk/blog/post/Using-Add-Deployable-Dependencies-in-VS2010-SP1.aspx) or [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg286946.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it was because I was deploying with a beta version but for some reason I needed to deploy nuGet.dll as well as Omar's list.

Also See:
Scott Gu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx

Comment: This is because you deployed System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll