# Click Once Winforms app has MVC dependencies (and it shouldn't)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Winforms app that was deploying to Windows Azure blob storage and running nicely until tonight. There is nothing fancy to this app - it has a dozen forms, uses a couple of Telerik controls and talks to an SQLExpress Database using the Enterprise Library.

After deploying my latest update and testing on the client PC, the application first wanted Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll deployed as well. I thought this was quite odd, so searched the solution looking for a reference I may have accidentally added and could not find any trace. Several cleans/rebuild and redeploys later, I still can't remove the dependency.

Eventually I added a reference to the dll, set copy local true, deployed, and now the app wants System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.0 - What the?! A bit more googling and trying a few more things and I realise that my project seems to have a dependency on other MVC related dll's (System.Web.Razor and so on.... similar to this [MVC3 Deployment Dependency Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742894/mvc3-deployment-dependency-problems)).

I can't find any reference to any MVC components (and I don't need/want any). What am I missing? I'm slowly migrating the project to use entity framework, and on the off chance that this was causing the problem, I removed the entity framework data access project (which had nothing except a model in it so far), this made no difference. Is having this project in the solution at some point causing the dependency problem? I'm really clutching at straws now.

I'm using VS2013 update 2, .NET45

Comment: Debugging ClickOnce is no fun at all, I wish you luck :(

Comment: Maybe the dependency comes along with a NuGet package. Did you take a look at those?

Comment: Thanks @Herdo. I checked the NuGet packages and none have dependencies. I don't have many to check - Enterprise Library, NUnit, Humanizer and Raygun.

Comment: Just an update, I'm no further with the click once deployment, but I have found that if I copy the application onto the client pc it will run without error. No good for my update mechanism though.

Comment: I found it *sigh*. Close inspection of the manifest showed the prerequisite files. There is a button on the Publish tab - "Application Files". The mentioned dependencies were found here, marked as 'prerequisites'. I 'excluded' the files, published, and the problem is solved. If I return to this setting now, the files are no longer available as a choice. I still don't know how they appeared in the first instance. Note to self - have a REALLY good look at the manifest next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close inspection of the manifest showed the prerequisite files. There is a button on the ClickOnce project's Publish tab - "Application Files". The mentioned dependencies were found here, marked as 'prerequisites'. Once the files are 'excluded' the dependencies are removed from the click once deployment.