# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, rest, azure, asp.net-web-api

After successfully publishing my Web Api to Azure when i try to hit the api i get the following error.

Here's [a link to api](http://uninamaapi.azurewebsites.net/api/NewsFeed/UserNewsFeed?id=1)

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
```

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149851/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-web-infrastructure)

Answer (score 94):

I solved this problem by doing this:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web
```

To install Application Insights only to the Web/API Project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web YourProjectName
```

To run these commands, in Visual Studio open Package Manager by clicking on: *Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console*

Comment: Better answer is remove ApplicationInsights from config file if you are not using ApplicationInsights

Answer (score 5):

Using "Manage NuGet Packages" I tired to install `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web`. It was already installed. I gave an "Update". After rebuild application, the error is gone.

Comment: This worked for me! ApplicationInsights.Web  was *not* installed, so I installed via NuGet. Automatically added all references. Rebuilt, run, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

I have reproduce this type issue. Here is my reproduce process:

```
1) Create web App api with Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web installed.
2) Then deploy the App to Azure Web app.
```

Here is the web API worked screenshot:
[image]

Then I open KUDU tool, delete Microsoft.AI.Web in Bin folder, and run the site again. I get the same error with you, here is the screenshot:
[image]

So I can ensure that, this error is caused by the assembly Microsoft.AI.Web is missing. Please set the copy local as true as following screenshot, then redeploy to Azure web App:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pls, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149851/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-web-infrastructure):

> You will need to include the dll with your project and add a reference to it
>   as well.
>
> Here is a link to a similar issue already on Stack: [MVC3 Deployment
>   Dependency Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742894/mvc3-deployment-dependency-problems)

Answer (score 0):

All the Answers about "Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" are not directly solved the Error in my case. My WebApplication-Project did not accept the Installing of the Package (Rollback after a few Minutes of installing).

Then I tried to add the NuGetPacke for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web into a Library-Project, which my WebApplication use. That added the AI.Web-DLLs also to my WebApplication and solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a .NET Core application in IIS registered with a .NET Framework application pool.
Once I assigned an application pool with the .NET CLR Version set to 'No Managed Code', the .NET Core application started to work fine again.