# Issue Deploying MVC 5 to Windows Server 2014

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly, iis-8

Keep getting the same error when trying to deploy MVC5 application to new dedicated server.

I have tried reinstalling the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure package.
I have also changed the properties > Copy Local to True.

I have checked that the Microsoft.AI.Web exists in the published bin folder.

Still getting the same error message:

Anyone got any ideas? Is there a server configuration necessary for MVC?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   ________________________________________ Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.  Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Web' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack
>   type) +0    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name,
>   Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +95    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +53
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase) +44    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +61
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +49
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +558
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean
>   checkAptcaBit) +30
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +57
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +54
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList) +191
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
>   +1086    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +123
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +396
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +333
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AI.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +124    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +700

UPDATE:

I can deploy a basic blank MVC application fine. So I thought, I would just transfer across the views, models and controllers from the project I want to deploy. When I do this, I get the error again. Is there anything in code that could cause such an error?

Comment: this AI is used with Application Insights. If you do not need it in your project, you can remove it also. Otherwise, check  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776427/7974050

Comment: It comes as standard with blank MVC project, therefore uncertain as to whether I don't need it? @Amit

Comment: Check if in your web.release.config you are not deleting the assembly ?

Comment: @GGO the only thing in Web.Release.config is the following lines: 

    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

Comment: So it's not that. Have you compare this reference with others ? what property change ? Specific Version is on true ?

Comment: Checked the above, still no luck, so we uninstalled web.ai completely and now we get an Error 404. Looks like there could be multiple problems here @GGO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just to update everyone, uninstalling application insights worked for the error I posted, the 404 was a routing issue. When running locally routing is no issue, but on the server the routing is a little different (maybe the configuration is different). We chose to use `Url.Action` (in the views) and `~/Home/Index` (in our cookie checker) to achieve successful URL routing.

This wasn't obvious to begin with so hope this helps someone else!